# Root url file is not communicating with app url file

Tags: python, django

I've created a project from official docs. Everything is same but still I am not able to communicate with my root urls.py through my app urls.py.

If I use views to redirect to app urls.py they don't work. But same if do with root urls.py it works fine.

My settings are:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
```

root urls:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/$', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

app urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from polls import views

 urlpatterns = [
     # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
 ]
```

Simple view I am trying to present is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, RequestContext, loader
from .models import Question

def index(request):
     latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Please help

After removing the dollar from `polls/$`, I get a new error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^polls/
^admin/
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the dollar sign from the url that is including the polls urls.

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
```

Comment: Also tried this but no solution. You can see error above after removing $.

Comment: Don't put the dollar sign back. Removing it is the correct thing to do. Now, you are getting the error because you are going to `/` but you have not defined any url patterns for `/`. Try going to `/admin/`, or `/polls/`, which you have added url patterns for.